# How to show loading on connectionState when using snapShot Image.network. and have no connection to internet flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, flutter-layout

I have a snapSHot of user profile Image.network but when I doesn’t connect to the internet it show the error here

**image:**[image]

Instead of `Text('loading')` How can I fix that problem

**code:**

```
Center(
      child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: authBloc.currentUser,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // when data loaded
        return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                   Center(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: 
                  BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        child: 
                         Image.network(snapshot.data!.photoURL!
                            .replaceFirst('s96', 's400')),
                      ),
                    )
            ]);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.error is 
           SocketException) {
return const Text("Error"); // if has error withinternet or any
      }
      return const Text('Loading'); // waiting to load
    },
  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData) { // when data loaded
        return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
            child: Image.network(snapshot.data.photoURL
                    .replaceFirst('s96', 's400')),
            );
    }else if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.error is SocketException){
         return Text("Error"); // if has error with internet or any
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator(); // waiting to load                    
},
```

When you are requesting to server you can do like:

```
try {
    // request to server
    }
on SocketException {
    print('no network connection');
}
catch(error) {
    print('fetch unsuccessful');
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code But It's still says SocketException the same.

Comment: I've update the code from what I get so far (your code) But it's still says the same `Exception caught by image resource service: Failed host lookup: 'lh3.googleusercontent.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)`

Comment: What is your function which send request to server?

Comment: You can use `try catch` to request to server if didnt use, check my updated answer